# How to use Pandas diff() with other columns value as period?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe looking like this:

| Timestamp | description |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Parser starts |
| 12 | parsing |
| 24 | parsing |
| 26 | Parsing finished |
| 28 | Parser starts |
| 45 | Parsing finished |

I want to calculate the how long each parse took. I therefore want the difference between timestamps where `(df['description'] == 'Parsing finished')` and `(df['description'] == 'Parser starts')`. I know I can use `pd.diff()` but I can only find how to use it with a set period. I want to set the period based on the description value.

Expected output:

| Timestamp | description | difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Parser starts | NaN |
| 12 | parsing | NaN |
| 24 | parsing | NaN |
| 26 | Parsing finished | 26 |
| 28 | Parser starts | NaN |
| 45 | Parsing finished | 17 |

I thought of looping over each row but this seems counterintuitive when using `Pandas`.

EDIT: updated wrong value thanks to comment of @mozway. Made myself more clear with below table:

| Timestamp | description |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Parser starts |
| 12 | parsing |
| 24 | parsing |
| 26 | Parsing finished |
| 27 | Uploading results |
| 28 | Parser starts |
| 45 | Parsing finished |

I do not want the timestamp of `uploading results` (or other values in between `parser starts` and `parsing finished`) to be part of the diff. Therefore grouping on parser starts does not provide the result Im looking for. I only want the diff between `parser starts` and `parsing finished`.

Comment: shouldn't the second value be 17 (45-28)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `groupby`:

```
import numpy as np

# make groups starting with "Parser starts"
group = df['description'].eq('Parser starts').cumsum()

# set up the grouper
g = df.groupby(group)

# update last value with ptp (= max - min)
df.loc[g.cumcount(ascending=False).eq(0),
       'difference'] = g['Timestamp'].transform(np.ptp)
```

output:

```
   Timestamp       description  difference
0          0     Parser starts         NaN
1         12           parsing         NaN
2         24           parsing         NaN
3         26  Parsing finished        26.0
4         28     Parser starts         NaN
5         45  Parsing finished        17.0
```

##### with filter

```
m1 = df['description'].eq('Parser starts')
m2 = df['description'].eq('Parsing finished')

g = df['Timestamp'].where(m1|m2).groupby(m1.cumsum())
df.loc[g.cumcount(ascending=False).eq(0),
       'difference'] = g.transform(lambda g: g.max()-g.min())
```

Comment: Thanks! It gives me an error `numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U9'), dtype('<U9')) -> None` but I think this has to do with some wrong data in the column. Your idea of grouping by the "parser starts" is a great solution!

Comment: Yes, '<U9' indicates you have strings, you can force conversion to valid digits with `df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Timestamp'], errors='coerce')`, or with `pd.to_datetime` for datetime

Comment: One more question. I praised your thinking of grouping by first value, but this gives an error I did not foresee. There are rows with other descriptions between `parsing finished` and `parser starts`. I do not want these timestamps to be subtracted, which is now happening by grouping on the first value. 


Since you did answer my first question correctly I leave this as answer but Ive edited my post to make myself more clear.

Comment: @Damiaan you could mask all unwanted timestamps before processing, see update

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    dd.loc[dd.index.max(),'difference']=dd.Timestamp.max()-dd.Timestamp.min()
    return dd

df1.assign(col1=df1.description.eq('Parser starts').cumsum()).groupby('col1').apply(function1)

out：

  Timestamp       description  col1  difference
0          0     Parser starts     1         NaN
1         12           parsing     1         NaN
2         24           parsing     1         NaN
3         26  Parsing finished     1        26.0
4         28     Parser starts     2         NaN
5         45  Parsing finished     2        17.0
```